# How to set protocol using async java driver for ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to connect ArangoDB from my java program. I have used the official async java driver for arangodb. The document mentions that we can set the protocol using useProtocol() method. But, this method is not present in code and in javadoc as well. Can somebody tell me how can I set the protocol to HTTP?
The github document mentions this following code.

`ArangoDBAsync arangoDB = new ArangoDBAsync.Builder().useProtocol(Protocol.VST).build();`

But object returned by Builder() method do not have any useProtocol() method.

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake in the documentation. The async java driver only supports VelocyStream while the sync driver supports different network protocols.